# Store the result of a JOIN query in a variable

Tags: sql, variables, join

Looks like something is off with my answer to the following question:
A.How many Sales Orders (Headers) used ColonialView credit cards between June 2004 and (end of)June 2006. 
B.Store the output in a variable.

The output for the `SELECT @SalesOrders` is 1 . **Should it be 1 or should it be the same as the number
of Colonial Voice cards used (which is 729)?**

This is my code

```
SELECT  b.CardType, COUNT(*) usdCV
FROM    Sales-SalesOrderHeader a 
JOIN    Sales-CreditCard b
ON      a-CreditCardID=b-CreditCardID
WHERE   b-CardType = 'ColonialVoice'
AND     a-OrderDate  between '06/1/2004' and '06/30/2006'
GROUP BY b.CardType

DECLARE @SalesOrders INT
SET @SalesOrders = COUNT (*)
SELECT @SalesOrders
```

Comment: Your query is inappropriate for the question you are trying to answer.  Specifically, having the card type in the select clause is unnecessary and is messing you up.  Note that Rahul's answer does not have one.  You can also look at this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170078/sql-server-2005-setting-a-variable-to-the-result-of-a-select-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try doing it like

```
DECLARE @SalesOrders INT;

SELECT @SalesOrders = COUNT(*) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader a 
JOIN Sales.CreditCard b 
ON a.CreditCardID=b.CreditCardID 
WHERE b.CardType = 'ColonialVoice' 
AND a.OrderDate between '06/1/2004' and '06/30/2006';
```

Comment: Thank You Rahul. This works. I did a SELECT@SalesOrders and was able to get the same number as the query result. You are very good at this.